# How to create a new empty pandas columns with a specific dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with columns `'a'`. How would I create a new column `'b'` which has `dtype=object`?

I know this may be considered poor form, but at the moment I have a dataframe `df` where the column `'a'` contains arrays (each element is an `np.array`). I want to create a new column `'b'` where each element is a new `np.array` that contains the logs of the corresponding elemnent in `'a'`.

At the moment I tried these two methods, but neither worked:

```
    for i in df.index:
        df.set_value(i,'b', log10(df.loc[i,'a']))
```

and

```
    for i in df.index:
        df.loc[i,'b'] = log10(df.loc[i,'a']))
```

Both give me `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.

I'm assuming the error comes about because the dtype of the new column is defaulted to `float` although I may be wrong.

Comment: `df['new'] = ''` or `df['new'] = (np.nan).astype(str)` ?

Comment: What is the sense in using `pandas` data structures to hold `numpy` arrays?

Comment: I know it's poor form, but basically I've got these arrays and I want to be able to access them easily, but they logically form a dimensional grid, so instead of playing with multi-indexing I thought it would be simpler to just  do it like this (i.e I've got 300 "things", each "thing" has the same 4 parameters/attributes, and for each parameter I have N samples of that parameter).

Comment: @MaxU is setting DataFrame columns by `df['col'] = ....` encouraged? I might be getting confused by something else here, but I think I remember getting warnings when I tried to do that since you might not be sure if it's a copy or a view or something of that sort. Like I said I could be completely wrong here. Also `df['new'] = (np.nan).astype(str)` doesn't work (`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'`).

Comment: Do you mind sharing a few rows of the dataframe? Also, regarding the object column creation, `df.assign(b=pd.Series(dtype=object))` works?

Comment: @MaxU I used `df['new'] = ''` and then the above and it worked.

Comment: @Nickil Maveli This is gonna look terrible, but the following example should create the sort of structure it has `df = pd.DataFrame([ [ np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.3]), np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.3])], [np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.3]), np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.3]) ] ], index=[0,1], columns=['a', 'b'])` and I want to create a new column `log_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each row of your column is an array, it's better to use the standard `NumPy` mathematical functions for computing their element-wise logarithms to the base 10:

```
df['log_a'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: np.log10(x))
```

[image]